# ¿Cómo sumar días a una variable date en twig – Symfony2?

Tags: php, symfony2, date, twig, symfony3

Hace unos días se presento la necesidad de sumar variables en `twig`, para ser precisos teniendo una fecha por ejemplo: 2016-01-04 necesito sumar 540 días para esto utilizo la plugin `date_modify` presente en `twig` .

Para realizar esta operación se debe realizar de la siguiente forma:

```
{% set modify = '540' %}
{% set date = "now"|date("m/d/Y") %}

{{ date|date_modify("+" ~ modify ~ " day")|date("m/d/Y") }}
```

Con esto el resultado seria: 08/31/2017

---

En la versión en inglés coloqué [un post igual](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40874656/how-to-add-days-to-a-variable-date-in-twig).

Y recibí varias buenas sugerencias, como se de lo grande que es la comunidad de `symfony` en español quisiera saber si alguien conoce alguna otra solución?

Saludos

Comment: Lo que realizaste está correcto, y no existe otra forma natural de hacerlo, ya que son las variables y formas que twig hace; de todas maneras, recuerda que existen tantas formas de algoritmos como desarrolladores existen.

Comment: Ok. Gracias tu comentario. De todas maneras entonces dejo el aporte para otras personas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hay una forma un poco más elegante de hacer este código

```
{% set modify = '+ 540 day' %}
{{ "now" | date_modify(modify) | date("m/d/Y") }}
```

De esta forma, la variable modify podrá ser actualizada en el caso que más interese