# Sumar el valor de una variable a una fecha

Tags: php, php5, symfony2, symfony3

Estoy intentando sumar el valor de una variable a una fecha, y que el resultado sea otra fecha.

```
$hoy = $now->format('d/m/Y');
$dias = 36;
```

La variable `$nuevaFecha` sería el resultado de sumarle a la fecha de hoy los días que contiene la variable. He encontrado maneras de hacerlo pero con un número fijo, no con variables.

Es decir, esto:

```
$now->add(new \DateInterval('P36D'));
```

Pero no me funciona.

Comment: Relacionado: [¿Cómo sumar días a una variable date en twig – Symfony2?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/36829/15855)

Comment: Lo necesito a nivel controlador, o sea como se haría en php, no en Twig

Answer (score 2):

Entiendo que esto es lo que quieres:

```
$Date = date('Y-m-d');
$dias = 3;
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime($Date. ' +'.$dias.' days'));
```

Comment: Es exactamente como lo tenía puesto pero el resultado que da es 01-01-1970 ...

Comment: Eso ocurre por el formato que le has indicado  "d/m/Y" si lo cambias al que te pongo en el ejemplo te debe funcionar, y si lo que quieres es que te devuelva en formato "d/m/Y" se lo indicas a la función date("d/m/Y",...) Espero que te funcione

Comment: Sería bueno una explicación de dicho código editando la respuesta.

Comment: El codigo se debe utilizar como esta en el ejemplo y funciona lo probe en symfony 3.

Comment: @juanitourquiza no es correcto que intentes modificar la respuesta de un usuario, eso se consideraría vandalismo; si tiene algo que corregir déjaselo saber en los comentarios

Comment: vandalismo dice jajajaja. Lo que sucede es que ya le piden pero no hace la actualización además la variable esta en mayúscula algo incorrecto. Y en el sitio en ingles nadie se molesta porque le mejoran o modifican una respuesta si es para mejorar @alfap

Comment: @alfap jajajajajaja ya no sufras ya no se cambio nada.